# Direct Product of Group: Isomorphic Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, direct-product

Show that a Direct product of groups, $G \times H$, contains subgroups isomorphic to both $G$ and $H$.

This seems like a simple questions but I can't wrap my head around it. I've already proved that $G \times H$ is a group

Comment: Can you not simply take $\{e_G\}\times H\subseteq G\times H$ with $\{e_G\}\times H\cong H$ and vice verca $G\times \{e_H\}\cong G$.

Comment: (I answered this question before I realized that it's a duplicate. I'll delete my answer, if needed.)

Answer (score 1):

***Hint:*** $$\phi: G \longrightarrow G \times H, \,\,\ g \mapsto (g,e_H).$$ Show that $\phi$ is an injective group homomorphism. Similarly for $H$.